# Как объединить css файлы? Не надо сжимать, а именно все файлы объединить

Tags: css

Проблема в том что есть n кол-во файлов css. Нужно их объединить, что бы все классы были в одном файле.

Comment: ctrl c + ctrl v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Скрипт объединения и сжатия CSS файлов сайта](http://coderhs.com/archive/tight_css)

Небольшой PHP код для ускорения/оптимизации загрузки сайта.

- Объединяет несколько CSS файлов в один
- Удаляет комменты, пробелы и прочее

---> А если сжимать не нужно, то просто убрать инструкции по оптимизации, оставить только список объединения. 
Потом запустить и в просмотре кода увидеть нужное - если встроили на страницу, а если спомощью внешнего файла - в просмотре кода нажать на файл подключения общего css (с расширением php) - откроется в новом окне и просто сохраните как отдельный объединенный файл.

PS Сайт мой, и пользуюсь таким решением всегда, за редкими исключениями и особенностями.

Да - ну, а для хардкора есть онлайн сервисы объединения и сжатия.